# jQuery Modal Confirmation doesn't work in php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to build the jQuery modal confirmation dialog box on a php similar to [this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

This PHP page is embedded to a parent php page at the end.

The trouble is though I am able to get it to work on jsfiddle perfectly, I cannot get it to work on my php page.

[My jsfiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/bzGEE/180/)

My jQuery block:

```
var submitForm = $('#form_twake');
submit = false;

$("#confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        'Submit': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            submit = true;
            submitForm.submit();
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
$("#confirm").parent().appendTo($("#form_twake")); 

submitForm.submit(function() {
    if (submit) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $("#confirm").dialog('open');
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<form id="form_twake" name="form_twake" method="POST" action="index.php">
    <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Destroy" />
    </div>
</form>

<div id="confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

Infact, the contents of 'div id confirm' **get displayed all over the rendered PHP page**. Submit does submit the form , but doesn't pop the desired confirmation up. Is there any order of things for jQuery to process specifically for PHP? I have done all possible research and that got me a working JSFiddle. I cannot seem to proceed beyond that!

Any help would be really appreciated!

[Edit] Adding the php code;

Here are the CSS & libs:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

PHP form:

```
<form id="form_twake" name="form_twake" method="POST" action="index.php">
    <div class="box fade-in one">
        <center><img style="border:solid 2px #FFCC00;" src="<?php echo $bud ['profile_image_url'];?>" alt="Avi" hspace="5" vspace="5" border="5"/></center>
        <?php echo $bud ['name'];?></br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Destroy" class="twake-button" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Jquery and PHP are completely unrelated. All your server side PHP is done before javascript even gets a chance to do anything.

Comment: Is the code above what is on your page or just what is in the Fiddle? It sounds like a CSS issue? Did you include the CSS files for jQuery UI?

Comment: Thanks, I understand that but I can get it to work in jsfiddle and it breaks completely when I render my php. I have verified the imported jQuery libs too, in case PHP isn't identifying jQuery code block.

Comment: It's almost the same on PHP too (except a few php expressions). CSS, libs are added too

Comment: Almost the same isn't the same. Paste in your actual code, no the working Fiddle. Can you get the dialog to work just using a dummy button? Not using the form?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the original post with the actual php code too, nope dialog doesn't show up with a simple button either

Comment: Is this an https page?

Comment: No, right now it's just on my locahost, using WAMP

Comment: Just to add; this html is actually embedded to a parent php page:
'include('content.inc');
?>'

Comment: If it's all acting correctly but putting the dialog box all over the page then it's got to be a CSS issue. Try removing your style.css file and see if it works better.

Comment: Tried but no change other than missing custom css. It actually never displays the dialog, it just picks the div 'confirm' and displays it as a normal html block. Looks like jQuery isn't working at all,

Comment: What is this for? `$("#confirm").parent().appendTo($("#form_twake")); `

Comment: So you've pasted your ENTIRE rendered HTML that you got from doing a view source in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css file, have the confirmation div hidden by default:

```
#confirm {
    display: hidden;
}
```

Then, make sure that you are running your javascript code after the page has loaded. This can be done with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
   // put your code here.
});

</script>
```